# Dalvik JIT compiler on Linux X86 or Mac build

Tags: android, arm, jit, dalvik

As I've heard from [Google IO 2010 session](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/jit-compiler-androids-dalvik-vm.html), Dalvik JIT compiler just support ARM processor.
Do this mean my own build of Android source on Linux X86 or Mac OS X can not support JIT compiler?

Should I use some target board with ARM processor to test Dalvik JIT compiler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked about it by myself from Linux emulator. JIT is working with WITH_JIT=true build option. Also, JIT also useful even on the emulation mode. Linpack shows about 2x more performance gain with JIT.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out in latest Android source tree, and there is no x86 codegen there. That means you can only execute JIT on ARM hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

But, how about QEMU? As Android Emulator runs on QEMU with virtual ARM mobile device so, I think it might be possible to test ARM JIT compiler from Linux and Mac build.

Please see http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Thanks

Comment: Ah, now I understand what your're asking about - whether an Android image build on Linux or MacOS host will have JIT enabled. Sure it will - that's why cross compile toochains are for. You compile on one architecture to target another. And about the emulator distributed in the SDK - yes, it will execute JIT compiler. But that's not too useful in an emulated environment